# AC_FL_RunContent not working after UpdatePanel postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, flash, updatepanel

I have some javascript in a repeater item which calls `AC_FL_RunContent` to load and show a flash file (in each repeater item) when a link is clicked (link is part of repeater item).

I have a paged datasource showing the first page of video links. Five items on each page.

The show video links work fine on initial page when there hasn't been a postback from the UpdatePanel. Clicking the buttons opens a fancybox and shows the flash movie to play.

However after I have gone to the next 'page' of video links using the paged datasource.. (or try to subsequently go to the any other paged page') The AC_FL_RunContent does not seem to be working.

The fancybox still pops up, a test alert() with databound value still works. AC_FL_RunContent just doesn't seem to want to load the flash file.

If I remove the UpdatePanel. It works fine. But that is not an option i'm afraid.

So :

- Databinding is working
- Javasript still works (alert proves that)
- Fancybox is still working
- `AC_FL_RunContent` is just not loading flash file.

I have the following setup

UPDATEPANEL

--REPEATER

---- REPEATER_ITEM

------ SCRIPT

-------- alert('databound value');

-------- `AC_FL_RunContent`

Paged Data Source (within update panel)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done two different things in the past:

1. Use the Object tag
2. Wrap my AC_FL_RunContent calls in a JS function that is outside of the UpdatePanel.  If you need to pass dynamic params, just make a generic JS function with the params you need.